# how to make db2 Load load invalid value as null instead odlf reject whole record

Tags: db2, load

I'm using DB2 load utility to load data file into table, and there is a column of date. In data file, it's format is yyyymmdd and for null value it is 00000000. I specified dateformat after "modified by " and for records with valid date it loads perfecrty, but it rejects all records with 00000000 in date column. I dont want to reject those records, but to load them and set null in the date column, how can I achieve that?

Comment: LOAD into a VARCHAR (or INTEGER) and use a GENERATED column that a conditional DATE transform of the VARCHAR(or INTEGER) column.

Comment: or pipe your file through `sed`, or use INGEST, or use a staging table then copy transformed data to a 2nd table, or (if using Db2 Warehouse) use EXTERNAL TABLE, or use an ETL tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD` does not have an option to change how NULL values are represented in the input file. One option is a generated column

```
db2 "create table d(i int, d generated always as (case when i > 0 then DATE(TO_DATE(i,'YYYYMMDD')) END)) organize by row"
echo 00000000 > d.in
echo 20180101 >> d.in
load from d.in of del replace into d nonrecoverable
db2 "select * from d"
```

gives

```
I           D         
----------- ----------
          0 -         
   20180101 01/01/2018

  2 record(s) selected.
```